# WSDL2RPG.sh WS-Security

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I was wondering if anyone know if it's possible to insert a username token into a wsdl2rpg.sh generated soap request coming from a stub on an iseries? My best guess would be part of a axis handle?

I need to insert ws-security into the soap header....

Please help!

Comment: Which wsdl2rpg?  The IBM offering of the opensource one?

Comment: IBM offering. I didn't even realize there was an alternative    ./googling